# C# Dynamic COM in Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, com, windows-server-2012

Got an issue where I am a COM type in c# using

```
    this.rtwbType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId, true);
    this.rtwb = Activator.CreateInstance(this.rtwbType);
```

I am then doing some stuff, and when I am done I call exit on the rtwb - so it can close down, and then calling:

```
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(this.rtwb);
```

In 2008 R2 this is fine and dandy - but the instance we take to 2012 an exception is thrown here.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

like I say works fine elsewhere.

Any pointers?

Comment: The COM server quit.  Could be that it said goodbye prematurely for whatever reason, could be that you helped it doing so by calling ReleaseComObject() when you shouldn't have.  You'll need to research the problem better and pay attention to what the server is doing.

Comment: @JonH, what line throws this exception?

Comment: @Noseratio it is the release line that *appears* to throw it.

Comment: @HansPassant it does look like it quit - nothing else is calling release. The scope is the same so it shouldn't be GC. This is NOT an issue in Windows 2008 etc only Windows 2012.

Comment: Assuming that it is an "operating system bug" never gets you anywhere.  It almost never is, you won't find it and you won't get a bug fix.  Just as likely that the server isn't very happy about running on an OS it has never been tested on.  Work with the vendor or author of the server to get this resolved.

Comment: @HansPassant, actually this can be easily repro'ed with `InternetExplorer.Application`. I wonder if this is a new behavior introduced with Windows 8/ Windows Server 2012.

Comment: @JonH, I've updated the answer with how to selectively ignore this error.

Comment: Why are you manually releasing the COM object? This should be handled by the GC when rtwb is no longer referenced. You could possibly implement this in a dispose method with GC.SurpressFinalise, before the Marshal.ReleaseComObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code reproduces this error (at least under Windows 8.1):

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application", true);
dynamic ie = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

ie.Quit(); // this disconnects the COM proxy from the out-of-proc IE object

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ie); // throws
```

Apparently, the implementation of `ReleaseComObject` is doing something more than calling `IUnknown::Release`, when it deals with a COM proxy object. My guess is, it may be calling [`IRemUnknown::RemRelease`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc226932.aspx), which returns `HRESULT` with an error, so `ReleaseComObject` throws, because the out-of-proc object has been already disconnected and destroyed with `ie.Quit()`.

Presumably, this behavior was introduced in Windows Server 2012.

The best thing you could probably do is to ignore this specific error:

```
try
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ie);
}
catch (COMException ex)
{
    // I'm getting 0x80010108, rather than 0x800706BA
    // The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)

    if ((uint)ex.ErrorCode != 0x80010108) 
        throw;
}
```

**Updated:** this is the expected behavior for an API like `Quit`, it doesn't violate any COM rules. The goal of `Quit` is to provide an API for explicit shutdown. I believe it uses [`CoDisconnectObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) internally, as a part of the shutdown process. This disconnects all external proxy references, so the server knows it can shut down safely.

The fact that `ReleaseComObject` is still trying to do some stuff after that (like, most likely, calling `IUnknown::QueryInterface` on the disconnected proxy) is not a fault of the COM server.

Comment: I went down this road - however I log and ignore all COMException exceptiosn for the ReleaseComObject. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that `ReleaseComObject` is most likely to just call `IUnknown::Release` on the proxy(ies).  It's not the RCW's fault that the server pulled the rug.  It's simply exceptional runtime behavior, just that in this case, the application (COM server) didn't crash, it rudely exited while there were external references.

Comment: @acelent, `IUnknown::Release` doesn't event return `HRESULT`. How does it turn into an exception? Besides, there's nothing wrong for an in-proc server to disconnect external references, if explicitly asked to do so with `Quit`. That's what `Quit` is for, and that's the correct behavior.

Comment: You're right about the exception, it must be doing something more.  However, I disagree that `Quit` should do that, but the fact is that it does.  Its sparse documentation doesn't describe its brutality, so I assume it was implemented like this from the start and newer versions didn't change for backwards compatibility.  I.e. people used to expect that `Quit` doesn't wait for external references, so they trusted the IE process would really exit.  I'd say the COM server that the **op** is consuming is just alike, probably even without updates.  Unless he can actually change the server.

Comment: @acelent, I can reassure that `Quit` for `InternetExplorer.Application` has worked like this since I first tried in IE5.5. Same thing for `Word.Application`. I myself happened to develop custom out-of-proc servers, and used `CoDisconnectObject` for the same purpose, I don't consider this brutal.

Comment: I belive you.  I tried a few days with Excel, Powerpoint and Word 2007 and all seemed to wait.  With 2010, only Excel seems to wait.  IE seems to not wait no matter the version.  Good to know, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `rtwb` is an `InternetExplorer.Application`, as [Noseratio's test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22199338/800524) seems to replicate the issue rather well.

It seems Internet Explorer's `Quit()` method is not really safe to call outside the application's context, e.g. through out-of-process automation.  It violates the rules of COM server applications.

For instance, Office applications keep running while there are external references, even after `Quit()`, so this is really a bit unexpected.

For safety, you can let the reference go when quitting, using the `OnQuit` event:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class TestIE
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating application");
        dynamic app = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application"));
        Console.WriteLine("Created application");
        app.Visible = true;

        app.OnQuit += new Action(() => {
            Console.WriteLine("Entered OnQuit");
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            app = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Leaving OnQuit");
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Sleeping");
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // enough time to see if iexplore.exe is running
        Console.WriteLine("Slept");

        Console.WriteLine("Quitting");
        app.Quit();
        Console.WriteLine("Quit");

        Console.WriteLine("Sleeping");
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // enough time to see if iexplore.exe is running
        Console.WriteLine("Slept");

        Console.WriteLine(app == null);
    }
}
```

If you really need to use `ReleaseComObject`, discard any exceptions it might throw.  I'm not sure if you should discard only `COMException`, try it out during development.

Comment: I loved this solution for it's elegance, however Internet Explorer was just an example used by @Noseratio of this issue else where. My Com server did not have such a useful event I could hook into!

Comment: Can you specify which server is it?  With Excel and Powerpoint, one way to achieve similar behavior is to make sure you have a dummy workbook or presentation open that you'll never explicitly close, and attach to `WorkbookBeforeClose` or `PresentationClose` event and detect when it's closed.  Either way, if the COM server is yours and it quits with pending external references, you should probably fix that.  That is, you should call `CoSuspendClassObjects` but keep running until all references are gone.

Comment: @acelent, *"It seems Internet Explorer's Quit() method is not really safe to call outside the application's context... It violates the rules of COM server applications."* - I would argue this is a violation of any COM rules, see the update I posted.

Comment: Disconnecting remote objects should be done when the **end user** forcefully closes the application (COM server), i.e. the user closes the main window and is warned of the potential problems it creates to other applications, and still says "Yes".  `Application.Quit()` doesn't fall in this case, it's programmatic, the server should stay alive for as long as there are external references.